# Foreign keys in FMDatabaseQueue

Tags: objective-c, sqlite, fmdb

so I'm using FMDB library, and I would like to enable foreign keys which is done via

```
[db executeQuery:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON"];
```

But I'm using FMDatabaseQueue, initialised like this

```
-(FMDatabaseQueue*)queue
{

    if (_queue == nil)
    {
        FMDatabaseQueue* queue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:self.dbPath];
        _queue = queue;
    }
    return _queue;
}
```

and then I'm using it like this

```
-(NSNumber*)phoneDBID:(NSString*)phoneNumber
{
    __block NSNumber* phoneDBID = nil;
    [self.queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
        FMResultSet* result = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT * from Contact_numbers where number= ?;", phoneNumber];
        if ([result next])
        {
            phoneDBID = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[result intForColumn:@"contact_id"]];
        }
        [result close];
    }];
    return phoneDBID;
}
```

and I don't think Foreign keys are enabled in queue, is there a way how to enable them for queue, or I have to do it in every single query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two observations:

1. The only caveat regarding foreign key constraints with `FMDatabaseQueue` is that I would advise against using `PRAGMA foreign_keys` within a `FMDatabaseQueue` transaction (i.e. within a `inTransaction` block). [The documentation](http://sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_foreign_keys) for `PRAGMA foreign_keys` says:

   > This pragma is a no-op within a transaction; foreign key constraint enforcement may only be enabled or disabled when there is no pending `BEGIN` or `SAVEPOINT`.

   If you do this pragma from within a `inDatabase` block, though, you will be fine.
2. Your example does not illustrate `foreign_keys` in action. Foreign key constraints are only applicable when modifying data in the database. But you're only doing `SELECT`, so the setting of `PRAGMA foreign_keys` is irrelevant.

   To illustrate the use of this pragma, consider the following example. I create `book` and `author` tables, where the former has a foreign key to the latter:

   ```
   [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {
       success = [db executeUpdate:@"create table author (author_id integer primary key, name text)"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Create author table failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"create table book (book_id integer primary key, author_id integer, title text, FOREIGN KEY(author_id) REFERENCES author(author_id))"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Create book table failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);
   }];
   ```

   Without `foreign_keys` pragma, this works:

   ```
   [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

       // without foreign key constraints enforced, this will succeed, even though the author_id has not yet been added to author table

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into book (book_id, author_id, title) values (?, ?, ?)", @(1), @(101), @"Romeo and Juliet"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Insert 'Romeo and Juliet' failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);

       // obviously, this will, too

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into author (author_id, name) values (?, ?)", @(101), @"William Shakespeare"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Insert 'William Shakespeare' failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);
   }];
   ```

   But if I turn on foreign keys:

   ```
   [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

       // turn on foreign keys

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = YES"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Foreign keys pragma failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);
   }];
   ```

   And if try that again, the first insert of the `book` without a corresponding `author` entry fails. I can't insert the `book` entry until I insert the `author` entry:

   ```
   [queue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

       // with foreign key this should (and does) fail

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into book (book_id, author_id, title) values (?, ?, ?)", @(2), @(201), @"One Hundred Years of Solitude"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"First insert of 'Hundred Years of Solitude' failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);

       // but if we insert author ...

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into author (author_id, name) values (?, ?)", @(201), @"Gabriel García Márquez"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Insert 'Gabriel García Márquez' failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);

       // ... now this will succeed.

       success = [db executeUpdate:@"insert into book (book_id, author_id, title) values (?, ?, ?)", @(2), @(201), @"One Hundred Years of Solitude"];
       if (!success) NSLog(@"Second insert 'Hundred Years of Solitude' failed: %@", [db lastErrorMessage]);
   }];
   ```

So, the long and short of it, foreign keys work fine with `FMDatabaseQueue`, but I would only advise against doing it from within a `inTransaction` call.

Comment: Yes, I know that I'm not using foreign keys in my question,but in real code I do:). First observation helped me. But thank you!!

Comment: Except that you need to call [db executeQuery:@"PRAGMA foreign_keys = YES"]; instead of executeUpdate, which always confused me.